# VirtualBox Additions 5.0.16 mess up files in shared folder

Tags: apache, virtualbox, shared-directory

i'm using VirtualBox 5.0.20 under Win 7, guest is centOS 7.1 with virtualbox additions 5.0.16.

Problem is: When changing any .js-File in my IDE (or windows editor etc.), the content served by the httpd/apache Webserver gets messed up with undisplayable chars and parts of the file-content are cut off.

This started happening when upgrading virtualbox and the additions to the latest version and ONLY happens on .js files.

Remounting the shared folder in the linux guest fixes the prob until the next change to the file-contents.

Does anybody have the same/similar problem and a workaround for it ?

Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Temporary solution: login into centos system by SSH client and save the file by vim.

Answer (score 0):

Today I found a solution.

IDEs like PHPStorm or IDEA have a 'synchronize' button: when you edit a JS file, click it, and it will work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

thx - it seems the vboxsf-driver-behaviour was fixed in VirtualBox 5.1.x, it now works for JS-files again.